# Mozilla's profiles with Selenium

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, mozilla

I'm trying to create a profile for Mozilla Firefor in order to download a csv file without the dialog box:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', os.getcwd())
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', ('application/vnd.ms-excel'))

binary = FirefoxBinary(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile,firefox_binary=binary)
```

When I arrive to download the file it opens the dialog box and I the profile is 'default'. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What if you add

```
application/csv,text/csv
```

, i.e.:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('browser.download.panel.shown', false)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', os.getcwd())
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile', ('application/csv,text/csv,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/x-msexcel,application/excel,application/x-excel,text/comma-separated-values')) 
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', ('application/csv,text/csv,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/x-msexcel,application/excel,application/x-excel,text/comma-separated-values'))
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen', false)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting', false)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.useWindow', false)                                                    
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete', false)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone', true)
binary = FirefoxBinary(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile,firefox_binary=binary)
```

Comment: The same thing, nothing changes

Comment: Does it work with the new edits for those files you mention?

Comment: I made few modifications. Are you trying for other file types or just csv files?

Comment: It doesn't work neither. The file type is: "Microsoft Excel Comma Separated Values File"

Comment: However if I try with a XLS file it works if I use this "application/vnd.ms-excel"

Comment: I see. What if you add the following:
application/x-msexcel,application/excel,application/x-excel
I edit the answer with this. Let me know if this works with that modification.